# Why am I getting INF when dividing small numbers in PHP

Tags: php, divide, inf

I have two tables in a database. Each have a column (varchar255) with a small number (0-30). I'm only trying to divide those two and this is the result:
If one column has the number 6,575 and the other 1,291 the equation should be 5,09. It outputs **6**. Other/most results outputs **INF**

[image: Image with more equations]

The numbers come from a foreach loop from the database and this is the code from the picture:

```
echo $row["ton"]." - ".$row_w["weight"]." - ".$row["ton"] / $row_w["weight"]."<br>";
```

I have tried bcdiv and that outputs nothing and is_infinite = 1. What am I missing?

Comment: `3,932 / 0,979` is never `5.09`

Comment: You've issue while mixing concatentation with math operation. This will work:
`echo $row["ton"]." - ".$row_w["weight"]." - ".($row["ton"] / $row_w["weight"])."<br>";`

Comment: Sorry, wrong number/typo

Comment: try converting the values to int()

Comment: if you observe you are getting INF for values starting with 0.same goes 6,575/1,291 its dividing 6 by 1 so you got 6 as outout,so its clear after comma everything is ignored.

Comment: @num8er Won't work

Comment: The commas in the numbers are throwing it off. You'll need to strip the commas from the numbers or convert them to periods before you can divide them

Comment: @user3437098 cause Your values are not float values, they are string values which turns that it's being converted to 0.  So try to replace `,` to `.` and then wrap with floatval to convert to string to float explicitly. check this one:

`echo $row["ton"]." - ".$row_w["weight"]." - ".(floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $row["ton"])) / floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $row_w["weight"])))."<br>";`

Comment: @aynber Yes.. obviously. Thank you :)

Comment: try to change your databse datatype varchar to double

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the values (char strings) to float using floatval before doing the division.

The inf means that the result is infinite because you are dividing by 0 or  a very small number as a result of an unexpected value coming from dealing with chars as floats, as the program is not able to understand the decimals in a proper way.

Example:

```
$var = '578.23';

$float_value_of_var = floatval($var);
```

and your code could be something like this (only as an indication):

```
echo $row["ton"]." - ".$row_w["weight"]." - ".floatval($row["ton"]) / floatval($row_w["weight"])."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @aynber/@Ash-b for seeing my badly stored values.

```
$a = str_replace(",", ".", $row["ton"]);
$b = str_replace("," ,".", $row_w["weight"]);

echo $row["ton"]." - ".$row_w["weight"]." - ".$a / $b."<br>";
```

. instead of ,

**Can't set a comment to answer, but case solved.**